# Logged in users get logged out after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, session, web-config

I made a new MVC3 application and it's hosted on WinHost's basic plan.

The gist of the problem is, the app pool memory limits are reached and every session InProc is erased, meaning my users are logged out.

As per their documentation, I see this:

http://support.winhost.com/KB/a626/how-to-enable-aspnet-sql-server-session-on-your-web.aspx

Here is the contents of my web.config after following the steps outlined above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>  
  <connectionStrings>    
    <!-- REMOVED FOR PRIVACY -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>    
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
                  allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"                  
                  cookieless="false"
                  timeout="2880"
                  sqlConnectionString="data Source='tcp:s407.winhost.com';database='DB_41_xx';user id='DB_11_xx_user'; password='xx';" />
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.8.0" newVersion="4.0.8.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Here lies the problem:

My users are still getting logged of after some time. I thought using SQL for the session would prevent this issue.

Here is the relevant bit of code on how I'm loggin my users in:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model)
{
    using (EfAccountRepository accountRepository = new EfAccountRepository())
    {
        if (accountRepository.ValidateCredentials(model.Email, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }    
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your email or password is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

And here is some code I use to see if the user is logged in:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString AdminDashboardLink()
    {
        if (SecurityHelpers.UserIsPartOfCompany(HttpContext.Current))
        {
            string html = "<li><a href='/Admin'>ADMIN DASHBOARD</a></li>";
            return new MvcHtmlString(html);
        }
        else
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("");
        }
    }

    public static bool UserIsPartOfCompany(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        using (EfAccountRepository accountRepository = new EfAccountRepository())
        {
            var loggedInUser = accountRepository.FindByEmail(context.User.Identity.Name);
            string[] userRoles = accountRepository.GetRolesForUser(loggedInUser.AccountId);

            return userRoles.Contains("Editor") || userRoles.Contains("Finance") || userRoles.Contains("Administrator");
        }            
    }
```

Any suggestions? Maybe my web.config is botched and this is causing issues. Maybe I also needed to remove something after I added in the session information?

Comment: Is the user running the same browser session when you see the logoff happens?

Comment: Yes, I open Firefox, login to the website (hosted on Winhost). Play around on the same website for a bit, and after some minutes (sometimes seconds later), I am logged off.

Comment: When an asp.net app pool recycles, will this be null/empty? `context.Request.IsAuthenticated`? If so, this may be what's causing the problem. If I switched to SQL session, do I need to modify the way I check if a user is logged in?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to execute the login?

Comment: @JeffSiver: This is how users are logged in: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused some times because the garbage collector cleans the machine key assigned to your application and assigns a new key that causes the looged in users to log out. Solution is to generate a `machineKey` for your application and place it in the web.config under system.web like

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="###YOUR KEY HERE ###"
                decryptionKey="## decrypt key here ##" 
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
...
...
```

this link may help you http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: Thank you for your help. So I generated my key and placed it in my web.config. Do I need to set any other option in order for it to work, or is it just a matter of placing it in web.config and done?

Comment: Not going to jinx it, but it appears just adding this to the web.config file, solved it! :) Will confirm in two hours; I should still be logged on.

Comment: just placing it in the config would do ... `;)`

Comment: I am getting the same issue. @only Bolivian Here- have your problem solved by this?

Comment: @NituBansal have you followed the accepted answer and the link provided in it? check you web.config if it has a similar block provided in the answer if not then you  have to follow the steps and generate a machine key for your application

Answer (score -1):

Forms auth is not session related, at all. It has nothing to do with session state. Everything required is stored in the forms auth cookie.

Your timeout above is set to 2880, so 48 hours i.e. two days so I would expect timeouts to happen.

Comment: Ok, so the way I'm loggin in my users isn't incorrect and should work just fine. On the other hand, I too would expect a timeout to happen - but currently that timeout is not even close to two days, let alone two hours. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm using `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` to see if the users is logged in. Does this play nicely with SQL Sessions, the same way it works fine on InProc sessions (the default of MVC3)?

Comment: You can actually decrypt a ticket and check it (and log it) so you have a better handle on whats going on: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AccessingTheASPNETFormsAuthenticationTimeoutValue.aspx    are you sure you don't have other session checks anywhere else in your application? Some folks try to sync up (or assume they are syncs, which they aren't) session and forms auth timeouts but they won't stay in sync with each other. If you have code elsewhere in your application to redirect to login if session is null empty, that could be another source of your issue.