# aspnet identity user is signed out automatically after few seconds/minutes

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

if you start a mvc5 project from VS2013 applying aspnet identity. you will find in the _LoginPartiaView.cshtml the following code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated )
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ActionLink( "Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() , "profile", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>

    }
}
```

which means that with every request the user is being checked wether authenticated or not. That would be beautiful if it can be.

however my problem is that testing on the development machine, it works fine. But when tested on remote server [shared hosting] then the user is logged out after  being idle for a few seconds-minutes.

Then I searched to find this [SO - isAuthenticated result is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352931/response-isauthenticated-is-false-after-30-seconds) and the accepted answer said:

> the host is killing the AppPool in the server when it is a few seconds
>   idle.

and some comment says:

> do note that the AppPool will still be recycled every now and then, so
>   a small % of users are likely still getting that.

So I was thinking that session [mode : SqlServer] can be the solution; and code will check `session["userName"]` instead of `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated )`

the question is:
is using the session for storing user name and authenticating actions acceptable?
is there any other better concept that is applicable here ?

**Edit**:
Answering Brad Q; here is the relevant web.config set up:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login"
              timeout="180"/>
    </authentication>

    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />


    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
                  timeout="60"
                  allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
                  sqlConnectionString="Data Source=xxxx.net;Initial Catalog=luckysessions;User ID=xxadmin;Password=xxxx;" 
                  cookieless="false"/>
```

**2nd Edit:**

after reading this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730385/logged-in-users-get-logged-out-after-some-time?rq=1) I started to think again and wanted to add this question:
Is it related to web-farm server setup?

Comment: Out of curiosity (and to take one variable out of the equation) what is `Session.Timeout` set to?

Comment: @Brad I edited the Q.. plz have a look

Comment: Well, you may try adding `slidingExpiration="true'` to the `<forms>` node. But as you have it, it should be fine for 3 hours.

Comment: Thank you @Brad for the suggestion; but that won't explain or solve the signing out in a few seconds or minutes :(

Comment: I would need more information, like acter how much time does it appear to end the authenticated session. It could be apppool, could be your membership provider, could be how the user is logged in, etc.

Comment: @Brad appreciating your patience with me :) when i said MVC5 template using vs2013; I thought it gives full picture of the environment. The membership provider is the aspnet.Identity using EF 6.1 for storing it. Also appPool is not in my hand. I have shared hosting :(

Comment: No worries (and could be my miscommunication as well). I would have to say if it doesn't play well on the host, it's probbaly something to do with the host. Any way of getting more insight as to their setup? For instance, AppHarbor sets their apppools to sleep around the 20 minute mark.

Comment: Please how did you solve that problem ?? I'm facing the same issue now. On Dev machine everything is ok but on production host, the user is logout out after few minutes... Any Help???

Comment: @Tchaps That project was aborted unfortunately.. However my last conclusion as far as I remember was that my problem is that i used shared hosting and the website is stored on web farm.. So the user is logged on server A and in a few seconds he is served from Server B where he isnt logged there .. So my final advice is.. Go ask the same question on microsoft msdn dev. Forum.. There you may find more attention...best luck